# C++: When is a class implicitly copied?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

When is a class implicitly copied in C++?

I have a class that contains a unique_ptr, and therefore cannot be safely copied, and therefore, I disabled the copy constructor on the class by creating private versions of `X(X&)` and `X& operator = X&`.

I immediately ran into the problem that instances of this class cannot be returned, because returning actually makes a copy of the instance.

Are there any other situations I need to watch out for?

Comment: Do you *want* it to be copyable.  You can write your own copy constructor to do a deep copy of the unique_ptr.

Comment: Having a `unique_ptr` does not make copying unsafe, it makes it flat-out impossible (member-wise). You need to implement move semantics if you want to be able to return your value, and this is perfectly doable with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Classes in C++ are never copied, only objects (instances of classes/structs). It might sound like a nit-pick, but it isn't; There are languages in which classes *can* be copied, and getting the terminology correct is important.

Comment: Just make the copy constructor/assignment operator private and the compiler will tell you. Oh and always compile `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: @meagar: But in C++, classes can't be copied, so nobody cares. Different languages have different terminology anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG Obviously I care. And anybody who cares about actually using the correct name for a concept cares. If a langauge only supported addition, and somebody called it division, would you say "who cares"? The terminology was incorrect in this language in any context, but that doesn't mean we should pretend it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situations that come to mind are: functions that receives the class by value, functions that returns then class by value, and *any class or container that contains that class*.  Classes like std::vector will use move semantics whenever possible (you did overload that right)? but will be unable to use functions that require a copy constructor, such as copying the vector.  As GMan said though, you *can* make a copy constructor for your class, and do a deep copy of the std::unique_ptr manually, if you want to make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

Returning does not copy the instance, it *moves* the instance. You just forgot to provide a move constructor. In addition, classes are now moved when used in Standard containers in most situations in which they used to be copied.

In short, provide a move constructor and move assignment operator (and swap, preferably) and you should find that almost all situations where copies are implicit, they're now moves.